# Javascript/Html speechSynthesis doesn't work

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I tried this in Chrome,Edge and Firefox but it doesn't work.

```
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const speed = document.getElementById("speed");
function play() {
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
utterance.text = text.value;
utterance.rate = speed.value || 1;
utterance.pitch = 1;
utterance.volume = 1;
speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to assign speed, but it works like this.

```js
const text = document.getElementById("text");
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", play)

function play() {
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.text = text.value;
  utterance.pitch = 1;
  utterance.volume = 1;
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value= "hello">
<button id="button">click me</button>
```